# Spotfire Filtering issues

Tags: spotfire, tibco

New to TIBCO Spotfire. Have Spotfire which has 6 tabsheets. When clicking the first tab it displays  500 of 1000 rows. When I click the second one it displays 600 of 1000 rows. Oracle table has 1000 rows, the one read by Spotfire. Original author has left the company, and going forward need to maintain Spotfire code. Have following questions:

1. When Spotfire is launched, first tab loads and filters 500 of 1000 rows. There is no clue what Filter takes effect, and where it is residing. How to find all filters in Spotfire file.
2. When second tab is clicked, display initially flashes 1000 of 1000 rows, but suddenly flashes 600 of 1000 rows.
   Tabs 1 and 2 are displaying 500 and 600 rows respectively (different filters obviously,
   but no clue which filter where it is and what it does). Can someone help clarify how the 2 different filters are firing when user clicks on the tab.

Can I just get a report of all Filters (All types - Data, Filtering scheme etc.)
that are setup in the Spotfire document.

Thanks
Auro

Answer (score 0):

Each tab will have a filter panel associated to it.
From the top menu choose: View > Filters. This toggles the filter panel to the right of each page.

On the filter panel, you right click at the very top where is says 'Filters' and you can opt to *Show Filtering Scheme menu*.
It is likely that each of your tabs has a different filtering scheme, if different rows of the same data table are visible in the different tabs.

Some filters may be hidden. To check, go to the bottom of the filter panel and look for the sentence "Some filters are hidden".
You have the options to show all filters.

You can get a report if you write an IronPython script I guess.
But since you say you are new to Spotfire, I would recommend you start familiarizing yourself with the concepts first.
The Dr Spotfire YouTube series might help, or other videos about Spotfire filtering. E.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFe5sWbp5pE.